# how to I UN-evaluate .emacs init file without restarting emacs?

Tags: init-file

I added a custom auto-insert to my init file and reloaded the .emacs file with

```
M-x load-file
~/.emacs
```

And then later I revised the auto-insert instruction and reloaded.  Now I get strange behaviour because I have evaluated two similar auto-inserts.  How can I have only the most recent evaluation of my .emacs init file?

In a bit more detail.

I added

```
(eval-after-load 'autoinsert
  '(define-auto-insert '("\.c\'" . "C \"script\" hack")
  '( "stuff" \n )))
```

reloaded .emacs file

```
(eval-after-load 'autoinsert
  '(define-auto-insert '("\.c\'" . "C \"script\" hack")
  '( "other stuff" \n )))
```

reloaded .emacs file

then I had problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*In general*, you can't. Your init file is unconstrained in its ability to manipulate the Emacs environment, and there is no such thing as *un*-evaluating the code you've run. You could write new code which specifically reverses the effects of some particular old code, but only on a case-by-case basis. Restarting Emacs is the only general 'reset switch' there is.

In *this* instance, however, you have only modified a user option, and those *do* remember their original values. Type the following, and use the "Revert..." button to get rid of your unwanted customizations, and then "Apply" the changes.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `auto-insert-alist` <kbd>RET</kbd>